# creating Object with different data

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I was wondering if there's a way to create an object with changeable data.

Eg:

```
pearson = {
  name: "",
  age: 0
}
```

Can I do something like a loop that each time it changes these 2 variables and assign the whole object with the data into an array, but each time the object will hold the updated data?

Something like:

```js
    let pearson = { name: '', age: 20 }
    const pearsonsList = [{name: 'dave', age: 20}, {name: 'jessy', age: 30}]
    let arr = []
    pearsonsList.forEach((e) =>{
      pearson.name = e.name
      pearson.age = e.age
      arr.push(pearson)
    })
    console.log(arr[0])
    /* this what arr[0] holds
    {
   "name": "jessy",
   "age": 30
   }*/
```

how to make arr[0] have a different value than arr[1] where the object data always get overridden ?

Comment: You have to create a new object each iteration, otherwise you're just changing a single object.

Comment: how to create a new object each iteration ?

Comment: `arr.push({ name: e.name, age: e.age })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem here is your `arr` is storing the reference to your `pearson` object, which gets modified each time you set it, even after you push them into your `arr`.

A solution would be to construct a new object each time before pushing it in.

```
const pearsonsList = [{name: 'dave', age: 20}, {name: 'jessy', age: 30}]
let arr = []
pearsonsList.forEach((e) =>{
  let pearson = { name: '', age: 20 }
  pearson.name = e.name
  pearson.age = e.age
  arr.push(pearson)
})
```

An optional, and cleaner solution would be to use `.map` instead of `.forEach` too

```
const pearsonsList = [{name: 'dave', age: 20}, {name: 'jessy', age: 30}]
let arr = pearsonsList.map((e) =>{
  let pearson = { name: '', age: 20 }
  pearson.name = e.name
  pearson.age = e.age
  return person;
})
```

Comment: Would you explain what does map do please ?

Comment: @AdhamNawito https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: You'll use a `.map` when you want to return a value for each element in the array you're iterating, which seems to be the case here.